# No DB commits after message consumption in Spring cloud stream Azure Event Hub binder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, azure-eventhub, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have an event listener Spring boot application which performs the operation **Read from Azure Event Hub Topic -> Persist the event into DB**. 
I used the spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder(Version - 1.2.1)'s Sink to listen for events from my topic, and it works perfectly fine. However, that event is not persisted in DB. When I looked at the JPA created sql's there is no insert operation at all. I could only see the Select query being executed on JPA save.

I just followed the example in the link [eventhubs-binder-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/tree/master/spring-cloud-azure-samples/eventhubs-binder-sample).

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void handleMessage(String message, @Header(AzureHeaders.CHECKPOINTER) Checkpointer checkpointer) {
    System.out.println(String.format("New message received: '%s'", message));
    myRepository.save(message); // No Insert operation triggered
}
```

Any JPA save operation performed inside the @StreamListener annotated method is not inserting the data into the DB..

Any hints are highly appreciated.. I have to do something with Transaction Synchronisation(KafkaTransactionManager + JPATransactionManager) I suppose, but not sure..

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after spending a day on it.. Created a new JpaTransactionManager and used it to create a TransactionTemplate.

And performed my DB operations within a new Transaction created from the TransactionTemplate.

```
TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager);
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult()
        {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status)
            {
                myRepository.save(message);
            }
        });
```